# How to get the value of record from array?

Tags: arrays, postgresql

I need to get the value of first element of array records.

```
SELECT ARRAY(
    SELECT ROW(id, id_currency, id_user)
      FROM posts
     WHERE id IN (111, 104, 102) FOR UPDATE
) ;
```

Result:

```
{"(104,643,)","(111,643,)", ,"(112,643,)"}
```

How to get the value of the entry of the second element of the array?

Comment: post your expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT (ARRAY(
    SELECT ROW(id, id_currency, id_user)
      FROM posts
     WHERE id IN (111, 104, 102) FOR UPDATE
))[2] ;
```

You can use `arr[n]` to get `n`th element of array `arr`. By default PostgreSQL uses a one-based numbering convention for arrays, that is, an array of n elements starts with `array[1]` and ends with `array[n]`.

The following URL would help you.
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/arrays.html